# How to load or import backup file into new teradata database?

Tags: database-schema, teradata, dump

I'm working in Teradata Database Express 14.04

I took the particular database build( backup the database) in Teradata Database.

The Archived file is stored in /roor/Documents/TD_BUILD. The file extension of TD_BUILD is (.File).

Now, how to import that file into new Database in Teradata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore to a different system and/or database or to restore a dropped table you need a [COPY](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/Database_Administration_Tools/B035_2412_035K/2412ch06.20.24.html) instead of a `RESTORE`:

```
copy data tables(xyz),release lock,file=test;
```

Caution, restoring on database level drops **all objects** within first, i.e. ARCMAIN submits a `DELETE DATABASE`.

If you restore to a different database:

```
copy data tables(newdb) (from (xyz)),release lock,file=test;
```

Comment: I tried like this,   TDExpress14.10.03_Sles11:~ # arcmain       .logon localhost/dbc,dbc; copy data tables(newdb) from (mentisagent),release lock,file=test;  But its giving me error   :                                            04/28/2016 07:09:51  copy data tables(mentis) from (mentisagent),release
                     lock,file=MENT_B1;
04/28/2016 07:09:51  *** Failure ARC0202:from was not expected.

Comment: I'm having the database build file, I just want to know how to load that backup file with another database name in Teradata

Comment: is it possible in Teradata to restore the backup database to different database name?

Comment: @VivekHarry: When you check the manuals you will find that I missed the enclosing brackets, edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much again . it WORKED successfully.